# Osmdroid offline zip files (tiles) maps does not load on android 10 and 11 devices

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid, offline-mode

I'm working with osmdroid map in offline mode. I have downloaded tiles using Global mapper and zip tiles are keep in download folder(/sdcard/Download). **But on Accessing it getting below error in ArchiveFileFactory of osmdroid. It is Occurring in Android 10 and above.**. Given storage access permission also.

ArchiveFileFactory class. Getting Error on highlighted line,

[image]

**Getting Error On Access Zip File:**

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.ZipFileArchive.toString()
```

Below is the code:

Permissions using
[image]

and build.gradle config is as below

[image]

Osm Library:

[image]

Tried Both Permissions :

1.Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

2.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

[image]

Fetching Offline Map

```
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/map_file.zip");
    if (f.exists()) {
        String name = f.getName().toLowerCase();
        name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        if (ArchiveFileFactory.isFileExtensionRegistered(name)) {
            try {
                OfflineTileProvider tileProvider = new OfflineTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(getActivity()),
                        new File[]{f});
                mMap.setTileProvider(tileProvider);
                String source;
                IArchiveFile[] archives = tileProvider.getArchives();
                if (archives.length > 0) {
                    String mapSrc = Preference.getMapSrc(getContext());
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mapSrc)) {
                        Set<String> tileSources = archives[0].getTileSources();
                        if (!tileSources.isEmpty()) {
                            source = tileSources.iterator().next();
                            Preference.setMapSrc(getContext(), source);
                            mMap.setTileSource(FileBasedTileSource.getSource(source));
                        } else {
                            mMap.setUseDataConnection(true);
                            mMap.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        mMap.setTileSource(FileBasedTileSource.getSource(mapSrc));
                    }
                } else {
                    mMap.setUseDataConnection(true);
                    mMap.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
                    return Constant.MAP_ASSETS_KML;
                }
                clearData();
                return Constant.MAP_ASSETS_KML;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return Constant.MAP_ASSETS_KML;
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? @Rohan ?

Comment: @Matteo No. Still Looking into it.

Comment: Please don't use images for text as they can't be searched. See [this comment](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1743#issuecomment-1050006568) on osmdroid issue ticket: [File access and Android 11+](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1743) for possible workaround/patch.